# How do I scrape from a webpage in python that populates using Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to scrape the table on this website:
https://www.tradingview.com/markets/stocks-usa/earnings/

from what I can gather, the website's table initially loads with numbers that aren't correct. Then it uses javascript, google tag manager, and google analytics to populate the correct values. I want to scrape the correct values after the table updates.

Here's what I've tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.tradingview.com/markets/stocks-usa/earnings/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

b = soup.find_all('td', class_='tv-data-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell--big')
c_list = []

for c in b:
  c_list.append(c.text.strip())


c_list
```

Today it returns,

['250.813B',
'2.43',
'1.82',
'0.13',
'7.87',
'35.648B',
'29.114B',
'2023-02-23',
'2022-12-30',...]

These values are incorrect and are the values which load on the website before the table updates.

Any ideas? I am hoping this can be done with simple python tools and not having to use a google analytics API which I don't have access to...

Answer (score 2):

You're using request to fetch the raw page source. You now have to render the page, which implies fetching html-referenced resources, executing JS and building DOM.

There are more elegant solutions to do it in Node since Node is already not only JS, but also V8. For other languages, however, you would have to, in most cases, load a headless browser.

I would suggest to go with [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) for this. Keep in mind that Selenium is a huge library. You will barely use 5% of it. However, it's also very powerful and is an industry standard for regression testing automation, so it has the capacity to solve quite a range of headless web-rendering issues and automation around it.

Comment: thanks, I'll give selenium a shot.